# File Not Found Error Using Scheduled Tasks

Tags: java, jar, cmd, windows-server-2008, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to run a .jar file from Scheduled Tasks (Windows 2008 Server) and I am getting a file not found exception. My program searches for an .xls file, converts it to a .xlsx file, extracts data, deletes .xlsx file, and uploads info to our database.

Things I've tried:

- Running the program directly in the command prompt - Success
- Searching for the file using dir in Cmd Prompt - Success
- Putting .xls file on Desktop and Running Scheduled Tasks - Success
- FileNotFound Exception throws error with correct path to .xls file

[image: Error]
Possible Issues:
Could there be any admin privileges not allowing me to access the file from Scheduled Tasks? Why would the .jar file work from the Cmd Prompt but not Scheduled Tasks?
Thanks guys for your help. Willing to upload more information if it helps.

[image: Cmd Prompt]

Comment: Sure that the `T:` drive is appropriately mapped for the scheduled process's credentials?

Comment: Hey @Peter , I'm having trouble understanding what you mean? Where can I view this setting?

Comment: Scheduled tasks runs from the system account by default and does not have access to network resources.

Comment: Start>Settings>Control Panel>Administrative Tools>Task Scheduler>Task Scheduler Library select your task. Click on Properties in the right pane to change the account under which the scheduled task runs. Select as desired. (W7 - other configurations no doubt a completely different path to do the same thing...)

Comment: @Peter Thank you so much for getting back to me. I went into properties and it looks like the user is set to my user. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! When I use T:\ in my path I am referencing a mapped drive. My scheduled task was meant to run when I wasn't logged on. Of course T:\ wasn't going to be recognized. What I really needed to use was the UNC Path! To find the actual path of your mapped drives type in "net use" into the cmd prompt.

This helped me oceans!
[Windows 7 scheduled task "runs" but doesn't DO anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069875/windows-7-scheduled-task-runs-but-doesnt-do-anything)